# About first national top level domains in Europe

Tags: dns, tld, iana

I have read that some of the first TLD where registered back in 90s, including .cz, .pl and other. So domain `.SU` was. That was domains for national needs.

But who have rights to become a maintainer of national domain? How that procedure looks like?

I also read that `.SU` TLD was proposed by Finnish student. But how can a student register national domain that supposed represent country?

I couldn't find information about that on Google.

Comment: These are known as [ccTLD's - Country code top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain). That should help with searches, eg. also easy to find https://icannwiki.org/Country_code_top-level_domain which contains many more 'registrar' and 'process' related pages.

Comment: It's up to each individual country how to manage their TLD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all data on the IANA webpage at https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db or just query it with whois.

`.CZ` is listed as created on 1993-01-12 and `.PL` on 1990-07-30

You can go back with some in 1985 like `.UK` or `.US`.

`.SU` had a complicated life because, as a ccTLD it should not exist anymore as the country it represented does not exist anymore. However for non technical reason, it subsists. You can find some discussions there : https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2-2006-12-05-en

> But who have rights to become a maintainer of national domain?

This is a complicated question, and not a technical one nor a programming one.
In short, IANA uses the ISO list on country codes (with some exceptions, like `.UK` and `.EU`) and takes input from the relevant government. Now the problem is that some countries are not stable, and also change. So there are a lot of complicated cases. Some ccTLDs are also marketed as non ccTLDs (like `.CO` or `.TV`) because the government decided to give its management to some external companies, for some financial agreement.
"Mistakes" happen also, see for example https://medium.com/@Oskar456/stolen-sk-domain-717e070f6735

You can find more about the IANA process at https://www.iana.org/help/cctld-delegation
Each IANA decision to delegate a ccTLD to a country is associated with a "IANA report" listing the justifications. You can read them for whatever country you wish at https://www.iana.org/reports, like a recent one for `.TD` for example at https://www.iana.org/reports/2018/td-report-20180227.html

The core business is codified, before ICANN even existed in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1591
IANA adheres to that, and you can find further documentation at https://www.iana.org/domains/root/help

For more details in general, I would recommend you to read my extensive reply to a related question about TLDs and wars: https://superuser.com/questions/1332236/what-happens-to-country-specific-tlds-in-a-war-involving-that-country/1332238#1332238